What was the historical consensus re whether it's possible to go through life as a kind and giving person if you don't believe in God?
Throughout known history (the last 3 thousand years), the most common philosophical as well as casual answer would be No or Yes?

Comments have been moved to chat; please do not continue the discussion here. Before posting a comment below this one, please review the purposes of comments. Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an answer, on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.

You ask:

Is it practically possible to go through life as a kind and giving person if you don't believe in God?

Carl Sagan is accepted by many to have been kind and giving. He also said he did not believe in a God.
If you accept those statements, then the answer to your question is:

yes, it is practically possible to go through life as a kind and giving person not believing in God.

And if not Carl Sagan, there are many other examples.
A comment says, "one isolated case does not prove the rule," but one isolated case does prove practical possibility. Proof by demonstration is a valid method of proving an existential statement.

Sagan wrote: "An atheist is someone who is certain that God does not exist, someone who has compelling evidence against the existence of God. I know of no such compelling evidence. Because God can be relegated to remote times and places and to ultimate causes, we would have to know a great deal more about the universe than we do now to be sure that no such God exists."

This is what I personally think. For great thinkers, like Plato or Sagan, it is never a simple or unambiguous answer.

You know, Sagan was sort of wrong to say that. It is not on the atheist to provide proof that God doesn't exist, but on the religious to provide proof that God does exist. Russel's teapot. (+1, Lowri, not disagreeing with the answer here.)

@controlgroup: Or the various camps can simply agree that they disagree, accept that arguing about it is fairly pointless, and try to focus on finding common ground. A first step in that direction is to stop assuming that common ground is impossible, and accept that most people at the individual level are, in fact, good and kind and so on. The trick is staying in the positive sum space when dealing with folks from another pack or tribe; humans seem to have some problematic instincts when groups interact which drive them to think in zero sum terms.

Read Plato's Euthyphro and replace 'pious' by 'kind and giving'.
In this dialogue Socrates asks Euthyphro: Is the pious loved by the gods because it is pious, or is it pious because it is loved by the gods?. Euthyphro is nonplussed and neither he nor Socrates reach a conclusion. This is now known as Euthyphro's dilemma.
Leibniz ater asked whether the good and just "is good and just because God wills it or whether God wills it because it is good and just"
Another footnote to Plato...

I think I am going to answer with a classic bit of poetry by Leigh Hunt (1784—1859):
Abou Ben Adhem (may his tribe increase!)
Awoke one night from a deep dream of peace,
And saw, within the moonlight in his room,
Making it rich, and like a lily in bloom,
An angel writing in a book of gold:—
Exceeding peace had made Ben Adhem bold,
And to the presence in the room he said,
"What writest thou?"—The vision raised its head,
And with a look made of all sweet accord,
Answered, "The names of those who love the Lord."
"And is mine one?" said Abou. "Nay, not so,"
Replied the angel. Abou spoke more low,
But cheerly still; and said, "I pray thee, then,
Write me as one that loves his fellow men."

The angel wrote, and vanished. The next night
It came again with a great wakening light,
And showed the names whom love of God had blest,
And lo! Ben Adhem's name led all the rest.

(Footnote: When asked if he believed in God, my grandfather replied "yes, if you spell it with two o's.")
Grated seasonings, everyone.
